# How can I set Async="true" for all pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am sending emails asynchronous using ASP.NET.
I noticed that I have to set "Async = true" in the View.

The master page doesn't support this property. How can I set Async for all pages?

Comment: Note, that it is very hard to get fire and forget background work right in ASP.NET. You are probably not on a good path.

Comment: See http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/. The worker process can die at any time. Your background work is lost then.

Comment: [Here is another good blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) explaining a few options on proper ways to do background work in ASP.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it in the master page like this. Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094574/setting-page-async-mode-to-true-from-code-behind):

```
public abstract class MyBasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public MyBasePage()
    {
        this.AsyncMode = true;
    }
}
```

Then change the inheritance in the aspx.cs file to something like this:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : MyBasePage
```

**It can break the system when you set the `AsyncMode` property in anything else then the constructor.**

Comment: that's a good ideia. It's curious that this property doesn't appear in the auto complete in visual studio. Althought it compiles.

Comment: Nice huh! They set `Browsable` to `false`, since they didn't want you to find it. It can break the system when you set this in anything else then the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Open the find dialog and enter:

```
Find: @Page
Replace with: @Page Async="True"
```

Click the Replace All button :-D  To my understanding, you can't just do that automatically for everything.  It needs to be defined on each and every page.

Comment: This is true. AsyncMode = true does not actually allow async use (with RegisterAsyncTask)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to send emails in the page code of ASP.NET, why not use AJAX?  Make an ASPX file that responds to a POST like a login form and when POSTed, it sends an email.  AJAX is asynchronous and you can display progress in the active web page using it.  An intro to AJAX can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Personally, I use jQuery to do my AJAX work.  You may want to check it out: http://jquery.com/

And last but not least, if you'd rather not "roll-your-own" code to do this, check out a Web API for mail delivery like Mandrill: http://mandrill.com/

Answer (score 0):

Include tpl references.
Then do
Task.Run(()=> Sendmailmethod());
This is the quick n neat fire n forget pattern

Comment: You really should not do that in a ASP.NET application. Your AppDomain may be shut down before your `Sendmailmethod()` completes. If you are using 4.5.2 or newer use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(() => Sendmailmethod())` instead so IIS will know you have a background task running. Read [this blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) for more info on QBWI and other "Fire and Forget" options for ASP.NET if you are not on 4.5.2.

Comment: U r rite scott, but appdomain shutting down is a remote event , and IIS is still aware when Task.run is spawned in a graceful shutdown.Trust me tried n tested

Answer (score 0):

You can use this strategy if you have pages that don't have a codebehind.

```
namespace com.mystuff
{
 public class MyPage: System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    public MyBasePage()
     {
         this.AsyncMode = true;
     }
 }
}

<system.web>
   <pages pageBaseType="com.mystuff.MyPage" />
</system.web>
```

More info 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.pagebasetype(v=vs.110).aspx