# How to place Async="true" on masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, master-pages

In my master page I will load some data from the database. I have place it into an asynchronous method. For normal pages I place `Async="true"` on the top but if I do it on the master page, I have the following error:

> `myproject.master` does not contain a definition for `AsyncMode` and blablabla...

I've also search on the internet but nothing found for an asynchronous master page. Language I use on background is C#.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1937920.aspx?Set+Async+true+on+MasterPage+).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample uses the new **async and await keywords** (available in .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012) to let the **compiler** be responsible for maintaining the complicated transformations necessary for **asynchronous programming**. The compiler lets you write code using the C#'s synchronous control flow constructs and the compiler automatically applies the transformations necessary to use callbacks in order to avoid blocking threads.
ASP.NET asynchronous pages must include the **Page directive** with the Async attribute set to "true".

Master File contain master directive.

Master Page inherit **MasterPage** class of System.Web.UI which does not contain **AsyncMode** property..So **you can't use it at master page**.

Normal Page inherit **Page** class of System.Web.UI which contain **AsyncMode**.

Comment: It's important to note that setting AsyncMode to true will NOT result in being able to use RegisterAsyncTask/etc. It's pretty silly, but you have to set "Async=True" in the page's directive or else it will not work.

Not sure why AsyncMode has a protected/public setter.

Comment: @Zerkz It's probably protected so that it can be used from other classes within the Application at an appropriate time. Since the pages are compiled "as needed" according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx) I assume at some point the application reads it in the page directive and sets it in the class' instance. And since our pages inherit the Page class, we end up having access to it at a moment where changing it will no longer take effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in the master page like this. Found solution [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094574/setting-page-async-mode-to-true-from-code-behind)

```
public abstract class MyBasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public MyBasePage()
    {
        this.AsyncMode = true;
    }
}
```

Then change the inheritance in the aspx.cs file to something like this:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : MyBasePage
```

It can break the system when you set the AsyncMode property in anything else then the constructor.

Comment: try with inheritance and check..hope it will help

Comment: View sangram answer: Master Page inherit **MasterPage** class of System.Web.UI which does not contain **AsyncMode** property..So **you can't use it at master page**.

Comment: I have found out, I can get around this limitation, for my usecases. It's not impossible to run async code in masterpages as long as the eventhandlers are not async. Instead I use:
Task.Run(async  ()  =>
{
await Task.Delay(1000);
}).Wait(); ///U can ignore this Wait if you just want fire and forget. 

This probably doesn't work in all uses cases, but it covers my needs...