# How can I execute an async function in Master Page code behind file?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have an ASP.Net Framework (4.7) Forms Application.

All pages are using Master Page template. In Master Page Code behind file, I am calling a function that takes some time (async)

## Site.Master.cs

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(LoadUserFromActiveDirectoryAsync));
}

public async Task LoadUserFromActiveDirectoryAsync()
{
   var currentUser = await << some async method in different library >>;
   CurrentUser = currentUser;
}
```

When I run this, I get an error:

> This operation requires the page to be asynchronous (the Async attribute must be set to true).

I know that I should set `Async="true"` in each and every aspx file in my application. But is there a way I can just set this option in the master page?

## Site.Master

```
<% Master 
     Language="C#" 
     AutoEventWireup="true" 
     CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" 
     Inherits="WebApp.SiteMaster"
     Async="true"            // this is not valid for Master Page 
%>
```

Comment: Adding a await can't help! Even if code runs async, you have await which in theory would WAIT ANYWAY!!!! So, the post-back occurs, page travels up to server. You call some code async, AND THEN WAIT with await, which would defeat the WHOLE purpose!!! If you wait, then the page will be held up on the server until such time that code is done, so you gain zero here!!!  Only WHEN the code falls through, is done, does the page RETURN to the client side. So, you can start another process thread, but it can't have ANYTHING to do with the UI or display on that page. Waiting defeats the whole goal here.

Comment: Since you either wait, or you do not? Then you can fire off other routine as a new task/thread, but if that routine needs to change/update/show any value on the current page, you MUST wait anyway! The web page will NOT return back to client unless your code runs though. And if you make async calls, the code can run though, but once page  code is done, it terminates, and sends page down to client. So, if that async code has to display anything on the current page, you have to await, and thus gain nothing. Remember, the page class and code goes OUT of scope once done and page sent to client

Answer (score 0):

The sample uses the new async and await keywords (available in .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012) to let the compiler be responsible for maintaining the complicated transformations necessary for asynchronous programming. The compiler lets you write code using the C#'s synchronous control flow constructs and the compiler automatically applies the transformations necessary to use callbacks in order to avoid blocking threads. ASP.NET asynchronous pages must include the Page directive with the Async attribute set to "true".

Master File contain master directive.

Master Page inherit MasterPage class of System.Web.UI which does not contain AsyncMode property..So you can't use it at master page.

Normal Page inherit Page class of System.Web.UI which contain AsyncMode.

Credit : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31001383/9787228

Comment: Unless you use await, then you can't see the changes client side. On post back, page travels up to server. You then call some async routine, but you HAVE to put in a awiat to wait anyway!!! Only if you let all code fall through does the page THEN return back to the client. You can call/start another thread, let that keep running and page code fall though and THEN and ONLY then does the page return back to client side, and then is displayed. So, async code can't modify or have anything to do with the web page. To make changes to the web page, you have to do it BEFORE page send back to client.